# Script to check Flash version isn't really checking version

Tags: flash, batch-file, version

I need some help making the following work. It's worked before (with other software), but in the case of Flash, it isn't. What I'm trying to accomplish is checking the installed version of Flash. If the installed version of Flash isn't what I want, I want the script to uninstall the current version and install my desired version.

```
:: Check Flash version and install if not matching.

:: Set version to check for.

SET latestVersion=11.5.502.135
SET key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Adobe  Flash Player Plugin"

for /f "tokens=3 delims=    " %%G in ('reg query %key% /v DisplayVersion ^| findstr /i current') do (
echo %%G
if %%G EQU %latestVersion% goto END
if %%G NEQ %latestVersion% goto Install
)

:INSTALL
:: Kill IE & FF
taskkill /f /im iexplore.exe /im firefox.exe

::Uninstall Flash
\\path-to-server\Flash-FF-11.8.800.94.exe -uninstall

:: Install Flash for Firefox
\\path-to-server\Flash-FF-11.5.502.135.exe -install

:: Install Flash for IE
\\path-to-server\Flash-IE-11.5.502.135.exe -install

:: Kill Flash updating
COPY /y \\path-to-server\mms.cfg C:\WINDOWS\System32\Macromed\Flash\mms.cfg

:END
```

The problem is that it's not reading the version that's installed. Instead of echoing something like 11.5.502.135, it's echoing "%G". And since %G does not equal my desired version (11.5.502.135) it's installing every time.

So narrowing it down, the following is my problem:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=    " %%G in ('reg query %key% /v DisplayVersion ^| findstr /i current') do (
echo %%G
if %%G EQU %latestVersion% goto END
if %%G NEQ %latestVersion% goto Install
)
```

When typing it out manually, as long as I stop at "DisplayVersion" I get the info I'm looking for. But once I proceed to the last part of what's inside the (), that's when I get the errors.

Comment: Are you checking for *Flash For Other Browsers*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Macromedia\FlashPlayerUpdate" /v version') DO SET "FlashVersion=%%b"
echo %FlashVersion%
```

Comment: That worked! I had to change the registry key to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Macromedia\FlashPlayerPlugin", but once I did that everything worked just fine. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To check your the current version of Adobe Flash Player installed on this computer, you should execute this kind of batch file :

```bat
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in (
'reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Macromedia\FlashPlayerPlugin" /v version'
) DO SET "FlashVersion=%%b"
echo Current Flash Player Version Installed is : "%FlashVersion%" on this computer %ComputerName%
pause
```

---

***EDIT***

Someone of you can encounter such error (connection failed or Application initializing error) while he wants to install the flash player from their online installer,this is happen to me, so, i decided to create a batch file for fixing such errors by downloading the uninstaller and uninstall all previous version and download the latest Adobe Flash Player with a full installation (offline installers) and install it silently and in the background.

[image]

***[Download_Install_Latest_Flash_Player.bat](https://pastebin.com/Wrk1r8Sb)***

[image]